# How to get the img (src) link from the Zomato order page?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, src

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

PATH = "/Users/macop/Tools/ChromeDriver/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://www.zomato.com/ncr/dominos-pizza-connaught-place-new-delhi/order")
time.sleep(5)


link = driver.find_element_by_class_name("hppEfq").get_attribute('src')

print(link)

for name in link:
    print(name.text)

driver.quit()
```

the final error which I get:

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".hppEfq"}
```

Looking for list of all the link in img tag of attribute src of that page...

Answer (score 0):

There are no element with class name `hppEfq` on that page so I do not know what image are you interested with.
For example the main image on that page is `(//div[@height='100%']//img)[1]`

If you want all the images try following:
`list=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("img")`
Now you have a list of all web elements on the page that are images.
To iterate over this list of web element and get the `src` from each of them you can

```
sources = []
for img in list:
  sources.append(img.get_attribute('src'))
```

Comment: I have post a screenshot of the thing which Im looking for, please help

Comment: See my updated answer. 
Next time try to ask exactly what do you want to get :)

Answer (score 0):

As stated, there is no class that has that *exact* class attribute. however there is a class that does contain that. So you actually want to find the class that contains `hppEfq`.

Also, not sure what you're trying to loop through since you only say to find the first element. And Lastly, for that element to render, you need to scroll down.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


PATH = "C:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://www.zomato.com/ncr/dominos-pizza-connaught-place-new-delhi/order")

html = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html')
html.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)

time.sleep(5)

link = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("img[class*='hppEfq']").get_attribute('src')

print(link)

driver.quit()
```

**Output:**

```
https://b.zmtcdn.com/data/dish_photos/a3d/7ca006ec8907c2ae13fd006cf0853a3d.png?output-format=webp&fit=around|130:130&crop=130:130;*,*
```

Comment: Sorry for not clearly specifying my problem, and thanks for the solution but can you suggest/help me how to loop it for all the elements/image/items. I tried doing `link = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("img[class*='hppEfq']").get_attribute('src')`  but got an Error that `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'`.

Comment: that's weird. It's returning a list. Maybe I'm on different version of Selenium? try: `link = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("img[class*='hppEfq']")[0].get_attribute('src')`